# Manually full re-build the titanium project

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, rebuild

```
Detected change in tiapp.xml, or assets deleted. Forcing full re-build...
```

This line has been taken from the console of the titanium build after making some change in the file `tiapp.xml` in order to re-build the app(i-e force full re-build). is that possible to  full re-build the titanium app manually.

**Note:** It does not re-build if we clean the project from project menu

Comment: What aren't you seeing change?  Is it a window or a view?  It is a setting in the tiapp.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can rebuit the total app. just delete the Built folder in project. It will rebuilt every time you delete it .